# Devise Error redirects to incorrect form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have just noticed a problem with my devise sign up forms when a validation error is thrown

I have two forms, one for an individual and one for a company, to differentiate the two

```
<p><%= link_to 'Sign Up as Individual', new_user_registration_path %></p>
<p><%= link_to 'Sign Up as Vets/Rescue Centre', new_user_registration_path(organization: true) %></p>
```

View

```
<% if params[:organization] %>
  <%= render 'shared/company_signup_form' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'shared/individual_signup_form' %>
<% end %>
```

When validation fails on the company_signup_form it redirects me to the individal_signup_form (which is the default url for a new user registration)

Is there a way to tell the form to redirect to the form that is being used?

EDIT

I have overridden one method in the registrations controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   administration_index_path
  end
end
```

Would this cause an issue here ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you override devise registration controller or not ?

Comment: the only thing i have overidden is the after_sign_up_path_for(resource)

Comment: But in both cases your resource is user. So you have to override registration controller. You don't have registration controller. right?

Comment: im not sure what to override here though, could you point me in the right direction please ?

Comment: You would need to override `registrations_controller` of devise to handle that case

Comment: any ideas which action in particular?

Comment: you should modify create action

Comment: @Richlewis you want to confirm your organisation also?

Answer (score 1):

for custom redirections you have to override create action on registrations_controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    resource_saved = resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_saved
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      @validatable = devise_mapping.validatable?
      if @validatable
        @minimum_password_length = resource_class.password_length.min
      end
      if resource.is_a? Organization
        redirect_to new_user_registration_path(organization: true)
      else
        redirect_to new_user_registration_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT

you need to configure devise routes :

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
```

Comment: thank you, its not liking the Organization though, uninitialized constant error when validation fails

Comment: it depends how you did implement the difference between organizations and individuals...

Comment: well they are all users, but a user that is a company(organization) has a db column company_form with flag set to true.. the organization=true is used to load a registration form for a company.. does that make sense?, also why is it users/registrations and not just registrations ? thanks

Comment: hence you can change the condition to resource.company_form

Comment: it make sense to set the users directory because you often have to override devise controllers, and it helps to keep controllers directory clean

Comment: yes after some playing around this morning I found that i could set resource.company_form :-) but now my devise error messages are missing